# Effects of tariffs on company

Tags: international-trade, tariffs

How would Trump's tariffs affect an American multinational company? Would the goods that they produce be considered imports?

Answer (score 1):

In the case of Apple at least, the answer is yes: this article dated August 31 2019 talks about the impact of the latest round of tariffs on Apple products produced in China.

> Apple, the largest U.S. technology company by market cap, has its products assembled in China by Foxconn and then ships them to consumers all over the world. The Apple Airpods, Apple Watch and accompanying Apple Watch bands and the Apple Homepod are all products subject to the higher tariffs beginning Sunday. The iPhone doesn’t appear to be impacted this round, but could be subject to tariffs that begin Dec. 15.

https://techcrunch.com/2019/08/31/apple-products-under-pricing-pressure-as-new-15-tariffs-drop-sunday/

Comment: Links become broken over time, so link only answer are considered poor ones. Please   post at least the gist of the article. There is even a style for quotes!

Comment: Good point, thanks for the advice. Edited!